# Is it bad practice to getLastKnownLocation any time someone moves a pin on the map?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I have implemented GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener and attached to my map object OnMyLocationChangeListener so that whenever any movement is done on the map, I can receive feedback of these changes in the callback method

```
@Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(android.location.Location location) {
}
```

I was reading the Android Developers strategies documentation  (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) and learned that there is a function to determine whether one location reading is better than the current location fix

What I decided to do was check for a better location with every map change. In order to do this, I am passing in the lastKnownGPSLocation and the location object from onMyLocationChange callback. From my knowledge, calling getLastKnownLocation can be expensive and battery draining. This is the idea of what I am doing.

```
if (isBetterLocation(mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER), location) {
    // update my current lat/long
}
```

And the function for isBetterLocation() is the following:

```
/** Determines whether one Location reading is better than the current Location fix
  * @param location  The new Location that you want to evaluate
  * @param currentBestLocation  The current Location fix, to which you want to compare the new one
  */
protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true;
    // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/** Checks whether two providers are the same */
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
      return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}
```

Is this how this function is intended to be used? I have noticed that other people use this as a Service. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#working_with_location_data), in working with location data, the location data available to an Android device includes the current location of the device pinpointed using a combination of technologies. The direction and method of movement, and whether the device has moved across a predefined geographical boundary, or geofence. Then depending on the needs of your application, you can choose between these methods in working with location data.

- The My `Location layer` provides a simple way to display a device's location on the map. It does not provide data.
- The `Google Play services Location API` is recommended for all programmatic requests for location data.
- The `LocationSource interface` allows you to provide a custom location provider.

Also, from this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html), the [Google Play services location APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary) are now the preferred way in adding a location awareness in the app. Just read the documentation link above to know more information and sample code on how to achieve this.

Comment: yea thanks! I was just learning about FusedLocationProviderApi. I no longer have to which provider (GPS, NETWORK, PASSIVE) I want to use manually in code. It does it automatically. I am switching over. It will reduce my code overhead significantly.